# How to deploy Rest Web Service on Glass Fish Server/Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I had developed one simple Rest Web Service using Net Beans as a editor.I had also deployed it on Glass Fish Server on my machine directly from Net Beans but now i want to deploy that web service on another machine which may not have Net Beans installed on it and it will have Glass Fish Server/Apache Tomcat Server installed on it so how should i proceed for the deployment of that web service on that machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just export your application as war.. and then you can deploy it on any servlet container or app server like tomcat, jetty or glassfish..

Comment: I followed this instruction. I ended up having the webapplication working, but the restful service does not work. when i try to access the url i get 404